# EC2 DNS servers

Tags: amazon-ec2

DNS servers that are pre-configured on EC2 instances seem to be only: 172.16.0.23

Does anyone know if thats a dedicated DNS VIP for a specific region?  Should we add more DNS servers in for fault tolerance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never felt the need for anything else.

```
ec2-user@ip-10-112-39-42:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 172.16.0.23
domain ec2.internal
search ec2.internal
ec2-user@ip-10-112-39-42:~$
```

Feel free to change it if you want, though be aware that external DNS servers won't be able to resolve `ec2.internal` addresses.